# check port status on a server using q scripts

Tags: kdb

I have written a small script to check port status using q. It checks for the ports and runs an email if connection is refused, which works fine. Then I used an optional timeout for a port so it would not hang there waiting. Though it comes back with the comment "timeout" if a port is timed out, it also seems to kick me out of the function and does not get into sendemail[] part.

```
ProcessChecks:{[port]
            V:{@[value;("hopen (`::",(string x),";5000)");enlist]} [port];
            .keh.V:V;               :
            mail_body:(string V)," at .z.T time: ",(string .z.T);
            .keh.mail:mail_body;

  $[-6h=type V;"port accepted";SendEmail2[mail_body;"connection refused port: ",(string port)]];
```

The name space `.keh.mail` does not change and SendEmail2[] does not get sent, which is just a unix `mailx` command.

I will get `.keh.V = "timeout"`

```
    .keh.mail = " at .z.T time whatever the time is"
```

5000 is 5 second wait time and its introduction causes the problem.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Example: `.keh.mail - "timeout at .z.T time: 14:43:54.507"`.  Maybe your `SendEmail2` function is not working correctly. Try inserting `show` statements after each line to get more information about where it is failing for you.

Comment: It does not seem to get to the .keh.mail, I get `.keh.mail when I check. I deleted the old value for .keh.mail.  I had to raze mail_body to get "timeout at .z.t time ....". so it does not seem to get to sendmail[]. My sendmail[] used to work fine, but we do not get there anyways.

Comment: Try changing your mail_body to: `mail_body:(raze/) (string V)," at .z.T time: ",(string .z.T)`.  As the only difference I can see between successful port connection and timeout is the type of `V` .

Comment: I tried putting mail_body:"test" and I tried your line and commented out the part that calls sendemail[] but still get `.keh.mail when I put .keh.mail:mail_body.

Comment: Ok, so the error is .keh.mail. What is the current value of .keh.mail?

Comment: '.keh.mail is what I get if I type in .keh.mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is being caused by a stray `:` in the third line of your script. This is causing your function to return early. Try the following:

```
ProcessChecks:{[port]
  V:{@[value;("hopen (`::",(string x),";5000)");enlist]} [port];
  .keh.V:V;
  mail_body:(string V)," at .z.T time: ",(string .z.T);
  .keh.mail:mail_body;
  $[-6h=type V;"port accepted";SendEmail2[mail_body;"connection refused port: ",(string port)]];
  }
```